# What should I do if after receiving a verbal offer letter I am informed that my written job offer is put on hold due to some internal issues?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, hiring-process, new-job, job-change

I was interviewed by a very large firm in UAE, remotely since I am in Pakistan. The guy passed my interview and insisted on me to join since we share the same birthplace, coincidentally.

I was presented with the job offer and I accepted without much negotiation. (Via Email)

The next day I was informed that I would receive my written offer letter in 3 working days and I should begin the paperwork now so they can initiate my visa and ticket process. (i.e. document verification etc in Pakistan which takes considerable time and money).

But after 6 days I got a bit worried that why haven't I received the offer letter and mailed the same guy who had hired me to let them know that I have completed 50% of my process and arrangements and also let me know about the job offer.

He replied;

> Dear XXX, Due to some internal issues we have put the job offer on hold but will update you once the process is completed.

I replied;

> Alright, till then I will continue my process. Keep me posted.

Now what does this all mean and should I be worried?

Comment: You should ask if there's a more specific timeline on when they expect to give you the written offer.  If they can't give you one, forget it and move on.  Even if they CAN give you a timeline, I'd keep up the job hunt until I see the paperwork.

Comment: There are currently some scams out there involving jobs for foreigners in the UAE. Make sure it isn't one and don't spent any money on fees, visa expenses, travel advances, etc

Answer (score 13):

it means "don't hold your breath". Said otherwise, events outside your reach means your hiring process is delayed for an unknown amount of time, that could be counted in weeks, months, or years. It may even get cancelled.

The thing to do is to look elsewhere, while keeping an open ear.

Last month, we finally recruited a candidate whose first contact with us was in 2016, and her hiring had been cancelled at the last minute for budget reasons. Two years later, she was available again, the position was open again, and there we go.

But don't hold your breath, which means that the most likely issue is that you'll find another place elsewhere, and will never hear about this firm again. Or they might call you againnext week. That's not within our reach. Whatever will happen, the safest option is to go on looking for other options.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be worried, you should start looking for a job elsewhere right now. The chances that you will get a job soon are slim.

And if you hear from them again, keep looking for other jobs until you have a signed contract that forces them to pay you, even if you change your mind. Well, that's something you should do anyway, because sometimes things go wrong, but especially in a case like this, where they made a verbal offer and had to withdraw from it.